# How to fix MySql: index column size too large (Laravel migrate)

Tags: mysql, indexing, laravel-5, vagrant

I duplicated a project with a vagrant box which installs Debian, Nginx, PhpMyAdmin, .. With the new project the Laravel's `php artisan migrate` is not working anymore and I get the error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1709 Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes. (SQL: alter table `courses` add unique `courses_name_unique`(`na  
  me`))
```

When I make a dump (structure + data) of the working project database and import it in the database giving the errors on migrate, then everything is ok and it creates all the tables and data is imported..

How can I fix the size so that I can run the migrate method?

Comment: set the length for the key: **alter table `courses` add unique `courses_name_unique` (FIELDNAME(299));**

Comment: @BerndBuffen I want to use Laravels migrate method. That method creates the tables and fails. Why does the migration works on database server A and not on B? Is there a setting that is not set correctly?

Comment: You are probably using different charsets. While `varchar(255)` might be indexed with `utf8` - it will fail with `utf8mb4`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you're correct, the migration command creates `utf8_unicode_ci` on the working server, and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation on the not working one. How can I make the database create the correct charset by default?

Comment: How do you crerate the database in your migration script`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As you can see in the error message - "The maximum column size is 767 bytes", if you want to create an index on it. A `VARCHAR(255)` column can take up to 765 (255*3) bytes using `utf8` and 1020 (255*4) bytes using `utf8mb4`. This is because in MySQL `utf8` takes up to 3 bytes and `utf8mb4` up to 4 bytes (the real UTF8). Thus creating a `VARCHAR(255)` (unique) index with `utf8mb4` will fail.

This are your options to fix the problem:

Set default collation in `my.ini`:

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

Set default collation for the database when creating:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `your_db` COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Set default collation for the table/column. (I don't recommend that)

Change the column size to 190 (`varchar(190)`) or less.

### **Laravel 5.4 fix**

The Mysql server configuration is overwriten by Laravel's migration command. It will set the collation and charset to the configuration's version.

Change the fields `charset` and `collation` of the db engine in the database config file located in `config/database.php`.

```
..
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            //'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            //'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
..
```

Comment: Thanks, you had put me on the right track! The server config you provided didn't work because the latest version of laravel (5.4) changed the default collation and charset. I updated your answer to also include the Laravel fix.

Comment: Or you can follow this answer which is better : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786359/laravel-migration-unique-key-is-too-long-even-if-specified/39750202#39750202

Answer (score 20):

For mariadb, update your `*my.cnf` file with following configuration,

```
innodb_default_row_format=dynamic
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_file_per_table=true
innodb_large_prefix=true
```

Then, you have to restart `mariadb` service for updated configuration to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the [row format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html) option  - I had the other config but not that, so my key length was stuck at 767.

Comment: for me, I had to edit */etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql_innodb_custom.cnf* on my Ubuntu server 18.04 and add the line  `innodb_default_row_format=dynamic`

Comment: This doesn't work!! I added those lines and my mariadb stopped working!!

Answer (score 8):

For Laravel 5.5 or higher change on your config/database.php file the engine to InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC:

```
'connections' => [
    ...
    'mysql' => [
        ...
        'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
 ]]
```

Thanks to laracasts: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/migrations-and-table-options-row-format

Answer (score 7):

Three solutions, each with a drawback:

- MySQL 5.7 avoids the problem.  Consider upgrading.
- `VARCHAR(255)` is usually var bigger than *necessary*.  If you can safely shrink to 191 or less, the error will go away.
- Switch to utf8 (from utf8mb4), *if* you don't need Chinese or Emoji.

2 more options here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: More details about "191" are in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: > "MySQL 5.7 avoids the problem", you mean because they have the [`innodb_large_prefix`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) [enabled by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-7.html)?

Comment: @guessimtoolate - yes.  (and some related things; see my link)

Answer (score 6):

In `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`, import `Schema` with:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

and in the `boot()` function add this line:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Answer (score 4):

By default MySQL uses the character set utf8 which means that we use 3 bytes for every 1 character. This means, column type of varchar(10) uses 30 bytes resulting in the max prefix size for compact row format to be equivalent to varchar(255). That is 255 * 3bytes = 765 bytes which is, two bytes less than the max of 767 bytes.

With innodb_large_prefix set to on and using row format COMPRESSED or DYNAMIC, you can increase the max prefix character size to 65536 bytes instead of 767 bytes. The below chart shows the max character length with InnoDB large prefix and [COMPRESSED| DYNAMIC] row formats. These values, expect for utf8mb4, are higher than the maximum row size of a table, so there is no way to hit these limits

More info here
https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/115004086747-Apps-are-down-due-to-the-Maximum-Column-Size-is-767-bytes-Constraint-in-MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Also had this issue what I just did, was revert from utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8_unicode_ci in the db connection script

Comment: utf8_general_ci is deprecated. Use utf8mb4 instead.

Comment: In Laravel 8, I applied this suggestion (utf8 / utf8_unicode_ci) and it works perfectly with MySQL 5.7.36

Answer (score 0):

It works with *5.5.52-MariaDB*.

Set all encoding to *`utf8_general_ci`* (server, database, connection).

Comment: utf8_general_ci is deprecated. Use utf8mb4 instead.