# How to enable large index in MariaDB 10?

Tags: mysql, indexing, utf-8, mariadb

In Debian Jessie I installed MariaDB server 10.0.30 and I try to increase max key length. AFAIU it depends of the config parameter `innodb_large_prefix` being enabled. According to the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_large_prefix), it also requires `barracuda` file format and `innodb_file_per_table`. After setting them in config and restarting server I see in client, that those parameters are set correctly:

```
> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_large%';
+---------------------+-------+
| Variable_name       | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| innodb_large_prefix | ON    |
+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file%';
+--------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name            | Value     |
+--------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_file_format       | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_format_check | OFF       |
| innodb_file_format_max   | Antelope  |
| innodb_file_per_table    | ON        |
+--------------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_page%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| innodb_page_size | 16384 |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not sure, why `innodb_file_format_max` is set `Antelope`, but while `innodb_file_format_check` is OFF, it should not matter. Actually, even if I had it also set `Barracuda`, it did not made difference.

If i try now create table with large index like:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `some_tableID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column` varchar(750) COLLATE utf8mb4_estonian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`some_tableID`),
  KEY `column` (`column`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_estonian_ci;
```

I get error:

```
ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 with mysql server 5.7.17 are all related settings same (by default) and there is no problem with large index (for utf8mb4 it is 750*4 = 3000).

What is wrong with my MariaDB setup?

Comment: And if you add `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` ?

Comment: @Hackerman, can't test anymore, because gave up on MariaDB and went back to MySQL

Comment: FWIW it's not related to MariaDB; MySQL 5.6 has the same issue. It's also not an issue in MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778785/2137210 for solution

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It requires more than just those two settings...

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
logout & login (to get the global values);
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;  -- or COMPRESSED
```

Perhaps all you need is to add `ROW_FORMAT=...` to your `CREATE TABLE`.

These instructions are needed for 5.6.3 up to 5.7.7.  Beginning with 5.7.7, the system defaults correctly to handle larger fields.

Alternatively, you could use a "prefix" index:

```
INDEX(column(191))
```

(But prefix indexing is flawed in many ways.)

"If the server later creates a higher table format, innodb_file_format_max is set to that value" implies that that setting is not an issue.

Comment: I installed test machine and can now confirm: adding `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` into `CREATE TABLE`-statement was the missing piece. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `ALTER TABLE`, you can set `innodb_default_row_format=DYNAMIC` before creating it. In any case, I would add all of these global values to the server configuration. Saves remembering all of this the next time something wants to create "large" indices.

Comment: Or upgrade to 5.7 and not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 12):

`innodb_large_prefix` only applies to `COMPRESSED` and `DYNAMIC` row formats.

MariaDB 10.0 and 10.1 have InnoDB 5.6, which by default creates tables with `ROW_FORMAT=Compact` (even if `innodb_file_format` is set to `Barracuda`). So, to use large prefixes, you need to specify the row format explicitly. Same is true for MySQL 5.6.

InnoDB 5.7 by default creates the table with `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`, which is why the same `CREATE` relying on `innodb_large_prefix` works in MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10.2 without any additional clauses.

Answer (score 5):

After the steps provided by @Rick :

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
-- logout & login (to get the global values);
```

I changed last step to

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format=DYNAMIC;
```

So far so good.

Answer (score 3):

I think solution is answered here for the session but if you restart the MySQL, I don't think these settings will work.

For the permanent solution, you need to enter following code in your My.Ini file-

```
## Innodb settings to bypass error of max size 737
innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=ON
innodb-large-prefix=ON
## Above 3 didnot work so i added below
innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC'
```

Hope it helps reducing rework and scratches on your head :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` in my CREATE query worked for me.

in your case it would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `some_tableID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column` varchar(750) COLLATE utf8mb4_estonian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`some_tableID`),
  KEY `column` (`column`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_estonian_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```