# Incompatibility between server and localhost charset

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, character-encoding, mariadb, amazon-rds

I'm currently developing a Spring Boot App with MariaDB as a Database. My localhost is a Windows 10 installation and the production server is a AWS Linux (first gen) image.

On localhost I have a local MariaDB installation.
On production I have a AWS RDS instance running MariaDB, default parameters.

Currently the problem I facing is the following, I'm trying to save the following characters ["↑", "↓", "→", "←"] to DB. On localhost characters are save as excepted. On the production server characters are saved as "?". Both DB's have the same mysqldump file.

I already debugged both Spring instances and they both receive parameters as intended.

Any ideas?

**Extra 1:**

**The only big difference between both instance is that localhost runs with the ./mvnw command while the production site is a generated jar running inside a Docker container.**

Comment: What does `SELECT HEX('↑')` return on AWS and on localhost?

Comment: Localhost -> E28691, AWS -> E28691

Comment: Logs from live-server: https://pastebin.com/Q43A4snm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In utf8 (or utf8mb4), those characters are hex E28691 E28693 E28692 E28690

See "question mark" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for an explanation of the step you failed to do.

In addition, check for `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the `getConnection()` call.

Comment: Ok so I checked the encoding issue, I did a full table restructure with utf8mb4 additionally I had to add some parameters such as the innodb_large_prefix (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379717/how-to-enable-large-index-in-mariadb-10/43403017) in order to get indexes working. Lastly I converted every String received using "new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)" . Finally after all that process I got it working.

Comment: 5 choices on the 767 problem:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes