# Why is this create table sql query giving me the error "#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes"

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members_table (
     `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `customerNumber` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `firstName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
     `lastName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
     `address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
     `city` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
     `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `zipCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
     `phoneNumber` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
     `emailAddress` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     `dateOfBirth` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `subscribe` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `password` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
     `resetKey` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
     `joinDate` datetime  NOT NULL,
     `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `emailAddress` (`emailAddress`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778785/2137210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157227/mysql-varchar-index-length) question:

> MySQL assumes 3 bytes per utf8 character. 255 characters is the maximum index size you can specify per column, because 256x3=768, which breaks the 767 byte limit.

Since you specified `utf8mb4` collation, MySQL assumes 4 bytes per character. From MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html):

> The utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character.

Your `emailAddress` field is 200 characters long at maximum thus the key length would be 800 bytes while error explicitly says the limit is 767 bytes.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks for answering. So, I'm guessing I should make it 190 or something

Answer (score 1):

MySQL assumes worst case for the number of bytes per character in the string. For the MySQL 'utf8' encoding, that's 3 bytes per character since that encoding doesn't allow characters beyond U+FFFF. For the MySQL 'utf8mb4' encoding, it's 4 bytes per character, since that's what MySQL calls actual UTF-8.

Use utf8 instead of utf8mb4

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members_table (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customerNumber` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `firstName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `lastName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `zipCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 `phoneNumber` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
 `emailAddress` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `dateOfBirth` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `subscribe` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
 `resetKey` varchar(34) DEFAULT NULL,
 `joinDate` datetime  NOT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `emailAddress` (`emailAddress`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```