# Impact of InnoDB setting modification on existing/new databases

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I am using MariaDB version 10.1.38 on Debian 9.8, and I had run into (and solved) the following issue for two newly installed application (Directus 7 and Laravel 5.8):

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1709 Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

This fix is intended for both Directus 7 and my Laravel 5.8, where Directus cannot be patched using the `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` fix that worked for Laravel.


The [reasons for this issue are discussed within this separate form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043205/how-to-fix-mysql-index-column-size-too-large-laravel-migrate), however my question pertains to the impact of the fix.

The following changes had been made to the **50-server.cnf** file:

```sh
innodb_large_prefix = 1
innodb_file_format = Barracuda #usually antelope
innodb_default_row_format = dynamic #usually compact
```

To fix Directus 7, I had also changed that particular database's encoding to utf8_unicode_ci, but that only impacts that database.

My question is as follows: **What is the impact of the InnoDB setting modification for other Databases using this installation?**
Will this break existing schemas for installations (of something like Drupal/Joomla)? How would this impact a future application that use this MariaDB instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  Two more things are needed:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
```

Here is that method, plus 4 other workarounds for the 767 problem: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes