# MYSQL index column size issue after upgrading from from 5.7 to 8

Tags: mysql, indexing, upgrade

We have a RDS MYSQL with AWS. After upgrading the mysql fro  5.7 to 8, one of our table has been in error. "Index column size too large . The maximum size is 767 bytes.

We've tried to drop the table, alter, truncate, drop index, all these command responded with the same error above, I'm stuck, please help, Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043205/how-to-fix-mysql-index-column-size-too-large-laravel-migrate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix MySql: index column size too large (Laravel migrate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043205/how-to-fix-mysql-index-column-size-too-large-laravel-migrate)

Comment: Yes, I tried to set collation_server and character_set_server to utf8_unicode_ci  and utf8, but the table is still unaccessible. I also tried to set the row_format to DYNAMIC, also no luck.

Answer (score 0):

That should have been fixed in 5.7 and carried over into 8.0.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the exact version numbers, and any other details you can think of.

See this for 5 workarounds:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes