# keycloak/Quarkus - unable to start keycloak server duo to mysql error

Tags: mysql, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm getting errors trying to run keycloak/quarkus with MySQL.

When I run the command to start the server :

```
> kc.bat start-dev
```

Keycloak connect to the database successfully, but it stops after giving this error :

> 2022-07-04 11:00:12,758 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
>
> 2022-07-04 11:00:12,758 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler]
> (main) ERROR: Failed to update database
> 2022-07-04 11:00:12,760 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler]
> (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set
> META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:
> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: La clÚ est trop longue. Longueur maximale: 1000
> [Failed SQL: (1071) ALTER TABLE keycloak_db_test.REALM_SOCIAL_CONFIG ADD PRIMARY KEY
> (REALM_ID, NAME)]

The error message : "The key is too long. Maximum length: 1000 [Failed SQL: (1071) ALTER TABLE keycloak_db_test.REALM_SOCIAL_CONFIG ADD PRIMARY KEY
(REALM_ID, NAME)]"

I tried to this with Keycloak versions 18 & 17, and tried it with MySql 5 & MySQL 8 & MariaDB 10
I Also tried to enable innodb_large_prefix in my.ini, but still no go.

OS : Windows

The configuration file keycloak.conf:

> db=mysql
>
> db-username=root
>
> db-password=
>
> db-url-host=localhost
>
> db-schema=keycloak_db_test

Any ideas that may help, please ?

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Looks like Keycloak, during startup, isn't realizing that the data source you supplied is a mysql datasource. How are you configuring the database url and the database dialect?

Comment: @sonOfRa I did run the build command first 
> kc.bat build --db=mysql
and I changed the connection parameters in the conf/keycloak.conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging and with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36090911/8665772), I found that the problem is related to the MySQL engine type.

The tables created by Keycloak are using MyISAM, and InnoDB is the one that supports large values, so the answer above indicate that I need to add `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` to `sql-mode` values and comment `skip-innodb`, but it didn't work until I changed the value of `default-storage-engine` to `innodb`.

Then the server started and successfully created the tables with InnoDB type.